# C - VS Code Error debugging - Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB environment cd

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm having some problems to debug my files on Visual Studio Code.
I'm receiving this error

```
Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-environment-cd "C:\\Users\\rodri\\OneDrive\\Área de Traballho\\EX4"". C:\Users\rodri\OneDrive\Área de Traballho\EX4: No such file or directory.
```

Tried to research, found some similar problems, but none of them fixed mine.
Here is how my system files are organized

```
main(folder)
       file1.c
       file1.exe
       .vscode (folder)
              launch.json
              task.json
```

Here is my launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "gcc.exe - Criar e depurar o arquivo ativo",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Habilitar a reformatação automática para gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe arquivo de build ativo"
    }
]
```

}

Here is my  tasks.json

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe arquivo de build ativo",
        "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Tarefa gerada pelo Depurador."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

}

Comment: Did you re-type the error message instead of copying and pasting it? The capitalization in "No Such file or directory."  looks suspicious. Please make sure your project structure description matches the error message or explain how the error message is related to your project structure. (`C:\Users\myUser\OneDrive\Desktop\EX4` vs `main`) Please [edit] your question to clarify this, don't use comments to add requested information.

Comment: Yes, I did re-type it, because there were some stuff in Portuguese. The files are inside this folder. Here is the real message, I don't see much difference:  "Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-environment-cd "C:\\Users\\rodri\\OneDrive\\Área de Traballho\\EX4"". C:\Users\rodri\OneDrive\Área de Traballho\EX4: No such file or directory."

Comment: Please **[edit] your question** to add clarification, **don't use comments to provide requested information**. If `main` is actually `C:\\Users\\rodri\\OneDrive\\Área de Traballho\\EX4`, then state this in your question or better write `C:\Users\rodri\OneDrive\Área de Traballho\EX4   (workspace main folder)` in your project structure description. Copy&paste the error message to your question. Some programs might have difficulties with spaces or accented characters in file names or directory names. You could try to rename `Área de Traballho` to `workspace` or `Area_de_Traballho`.

Comment: WOW! You are right!!! The space was the problem! Created a file on "C:\EX4\ and it worked, thank you!! Already edited the main question with the suggestions you presented. Thank youuuu

Comment: *Extra info for those looking into the issue and why:* [a work-around?](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3444#issuecomment-626666984) and [another reference to the issue](https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug/issues/207)

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with the `Launch.json` file.

The file path should not have any spaces like in my case `prog files`. So I replaced and renamed the folder to `progfiles`.

```
"program": "D:\\Progfiles\\vscode\\hello.exe",
"args": [],
"stopAtEntry": false,
"cwd": "D:\\Progfiles\\vscode",
"environment": [],
```