# How can I fix VSCode C++ Debugging Setting Error？

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, gdb, mingw

I've followed the instructions online to set the C++ environment for compiling and debugging with using MinGW compiler.
But I've kept facing this error when I try to do debugging. It can successfully compiles the code, but can not do debugging.

```
unable to start debugging unexpected gdb output from command:"-environment-cd" invalid argument
```

Here's the error

[image]

Here's my setting in launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe 建置使用中檔案"
        }
    ]
}
```

here's my setting in tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe 建置使用中檔案",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "編譯器: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        },
    ]
}
```

Also here's my setting in c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:\\MinGW\\include",
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include",
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "__GNUC__=5",
                "__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__))"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "C:\\MinGW\\include",
                    "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include",
                    "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            },
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Any help with this error would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from the command -environment-cd "Path" . No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69619818/unable-to-start-debugging-unexpected-gdb-output-from-the-command-environment-c) also similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66658308/c-vs-code-error-debugging-unable-to-start-debugging-unexpected-gdb-environm

Comment: Try to avoid unusual characters in file and directory names. Definitely avoid spaces, pluses and the like. And, although this should not be the case, it may be worth avoiding Chinese characters as well.

Comment: Thx for u guys' help. The path name with chinese and plus symbol is where the problem happens... I'll avoid such mistake in the future